# Unwanted page refresh on jquery ui tab change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, anchor, jquery-tabs

1. I have used already Jquery UI Tabs. But in my new project I need simple tabs with detail. I have used [this jquery ui demo](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) but when I click on any tab it refreshes all page. (that is what I need to achieve in my work)
2. Now I think the problem is different little.
   When I use only anchor tag(Please note that I am talking about only anchor tag not about jquery ui tabs in this point), it refreshes page. I know if I use # in href that will not fire click event and page will not refresh but in my case it refreshes page.

I have also used `onclick='return false;'` still it loads page. I don't know why. I might not getting clue what I am making wrong.

(Point 1 & 2)
I have searched on web but still not getting any answer.
Screen Shots
[image][image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code or make an online demo for us.

Comment: You'll need to show some of your code if we can possibly help you out

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `href` of your `anchor elements` with `div-tab-id` like,

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat,....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Here, `tabs-1` and `tabs-2` are ids of `div elements` and given in `achor tag href`.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qEQB/)

Comment: yes. I have used that code. but It is not working. It refreshes page.

Comment: Just copy my code and try it. Remember you have to include all required `js` and `css`. Or show us your code.

Comment: I am already using that in my code. When I copy that code and save in other page it works like I want but not only in my admin panel.

Comment: Then check the page source, did you see all required js and css in it? Or check in console, is there any error?

Comment: Yes, I have check it and solved it already but that is not solving my problem.

Comment: I got answer. I was adding two jquery different times.

Comment: Yes.. That jquery Comes at run time. That's why I wasn't able to find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstood the DOM structure click on the view source on the specified URL and check the DOM structure
there is no # for href but instead #tabs-1 which opens up div with id tabs-1

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick:

```
onclick='event.preventDefault();'
```